# Unable to access outlook mail using R

Tags: r, outlook

I am using mRPostman package to access the folders in outlook mail. It gives me the below error after creating the object **con**.

> Error in response_error_handling(e$message[1]) :
> Login denied: the server returned an authentication error.

Code:

```
con <- configure_imap(
  url="imaps://outlook.office365.com",
  username="meenu@abcindia.com",
  password="Password@098",
  verbose = TRUE,
  )
```

Tried the `password=rstudioapi::askForPassword()` option too but the same error persists.

Comment: Can someone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to Office 365, the email you see is usually an alias and not your "real" email address. For example, we use Office 365 in my company and my email is `allan@company.com`. However, the real address is `3254339@company.com`, where `3254339` is my ID number in the company.
Please, check with your IT department/sector if this is also your case, and create ​the connection token like this

```
con <- configure_imap(
 ​url = "imaps://outlook.office365.com/",
 ​username = "3254339@company.com",
 ​password = rstudioapi::askForPassword()
)
```